# XmR Chart Control Limits - Why Moving Range - Why Not population 3sigma

Tags: variance, sample-size, quality-control

Why do we compute the control limits for the individuals or XmR chart with an estimated sigma, 2.66 x mR(avg)? I understand that the overall population sigma is different. But why is one more appropriate than the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply use three sigma limits you're not considering the possibility your data is not homogeneous. This article I eventually found explains it well.

https://www.qualitydigest.com/inside/twitter-ed/individual-charts-done-right-and-wrong.html